# Read Text File in Document Folder - Iphone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, documents

I have this code below:

```
    NSString *fileName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"recentDownload"];
    NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [textViewerDownload setText:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]];
```

- `textviewerdownload` is the `textview` displaying the text from the file. The actual file name is stored in an `NSUserDefault` called `recentDownload`.
- When I build this, I click the `button` which this is under, and my application `crashes`.
- Is there anything wrong with the syntax or just simple error?

Comment: If there were a problem with the syntax, your code would not compile; you would not get to the stage of running it and seeing it crash. To debug a crash, use the debugger; it should be telling you how you crashed and where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NSBundle` class is used for finding things within your applications bundle, but the Documents directory is outside the bundle, so the way you're generating the path won't work. Try this instead:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);

NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recentDownload.txt"];
```

Comment: Ok I changed some of the coding.. My application still crashes.. Here is the code under my IBAction: http://www.heliotop.org/code.rtf

Also how would I do an if statement, where if the recent file is not a file with the extension "txt", it would return, and if it was then result in an action..

Answer (score 6):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.txt"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs])
    {
        NSString *myPathInfo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:myPathInfo toPath:myPathDocs error:NULL];
    }       

    //Load from File
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPathDocs encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

This worked for me

Anyway, thank you all..

Answer (score 2):

For read/write from text file check this [url](http://iphonedevelopersunited.blogspot.com/2011/05/readwrite-txt-file-in-iphone-sdk.html).

Comment: Make sure you set the boolean flag “UIFileSharingEnabled” to `YES` in your info.plist.