# How do I initialize all positions in an array of numbers?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I want to store the same number in an array 100 times. These numbers will change later on, but I want to write an if statement using a counter to populate all 100 slots initially with the value of 0. Is there an easy way to do this?

Something *like* this, where 'block01' needs to change to 'block02', 'block03' etc.:

```
int block01 = 0;

NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

if(myDict)
{
    [myDict setObject:block01 forKey:@"block01stored"];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"];

    BOOL successfulWrite = [myDict writeToFile: path atomically: YES];
    if(successfulWrite == NO)
}
```

Comment: Two problems: you say array but show a dictionary, and an `int` isn't an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you. It's a loop that will execute 99 times (1 - 100) adding zero as the object for a key formatted to include the current number.

```
NSMutableDictionary* myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i ++) {
    if(myDict)
    {
        [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%.3istored",i]];
    }
}
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"];
BOOL successfulWrite = [myDict writeToFile: path atomically: YES];
if(successfulWrite == NO)
```

**EDIT:** To get the value for a certain key you can use the following:

```
int myInt = [[myDict objectForKey:@"block050stored"] intValue];
```

And if you want to replace the object for a certain key it's as easy as:

```
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"block020stored"];
```

Now, the `%.3i` tells the string to add a number (i) formatted to always be three digits long. (000, 001, 010, 099, 100)

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%.3istored",i]
```

So the above line basically means, create a string with the words "block" and "stored" with a three digit representation of what ever the current value of the int "i" is in between them.

Comment: Okay, I think that's more along the lines of what I need. Same questions as above though: How do I call back a specific number? (Say I wanted to know what was held at position 50 for example). Also how can I alter a specific number at a certain position? (For example I wanted to change the 0 at position 20 to a 1).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what 'block%.3istored' means?

Comment: It was the three digits that was confusing me, I only need to store 100 so can use 0 to 99. I've changed it to %.2i and it's working. Also, I worked out how to call the number back but with slightly different code:

NSNumber *mycallednumber = [myDict objectForKey: @"block01stored"];

Comment: Final question then: How do I load the 'blocks.save' file back in when the App is restarted?

Comment: @MarkStoneham This post should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709874/716216

Comment: Okay, I've used:

---

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES);
    
    NSString *myDict = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"];
    
    int calledNumber1 = [[myDict objectForKey:@"block001stored"] intValue];

but I get the error No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'

`code`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",myDict) shows the file is being loaded back in but I can't get the value as per your code without getting the error in my last comment.

Comment: @MarkStoneham That's because you are attempting to use "objectForKey" a property of NSDictionary on an object of NSString type.

Comment: So what should I be using? I can get the value as per your code above but it doesn't work if I load the 'blocks.save' back in.

Comment: If I use     NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"]; the App runs but crashes when I try to get a value (i.e. block001stored).

Comment: Okay, figured it in the end:


   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"blocks.save"];
    NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        
    NSLog(@"%@",myDict);
    
    NSNumber *callednumber = [myDict objectForKey: @"block001stored"]; NSLog( @"block001 %d", [callednumber intValue] );

Answer (score 0):

You can create NSNumber (which is an object, but int is not) and then store it into NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
   [myDict setObject:num forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%dstored",i]];
}
```

Comment: Great. How do I call back the numbers? (Say I wanted to know what was held at position 50 for example). Also how can I alter a specific number at a certain position? (For example I wanted to change the 0 at position 20 to a 1).

Comment: @Mark Stoneham: [myDict setObjcect:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"block%dstored",20]];