# Cleaning .txt in Documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, text, nsuserdefaults

I am adding .txt file to Documents folder for storing some data using solution founded here: 
[Read Text File in Document Folder - Iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709705/read-text-file-in-document-folder-iphone-sdk)

So now I can write and read text from this file succesfully, but I need also to have action what will clear all text in this file to make it absolutely empty. Is it possible?

Comment: well, the simplest way would be to delete the file then create a new one with the same name. you can use [this tutorial](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/data-file-management/iphone-file-system-creating-renaming-and-deleting-files.html) to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one line, this ought to do it:

```
[[NSData data] writeToFile: pathToFile atomically: YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

This will loop all files -in Documents Directory- which has suffix of "txt" and delete its contents:

```
NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSArray *arr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
for (NSString *fileName in arr) {
    if ([fileName hasSuffix:@".txt"])
    {
        [@"" writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: As of iOS 8, do **not** use this to get the Documents folder. It is no longer just off of the "home" directory.